# Having multiple sockets open at the same time

Tags: java, android

I need to have 2 different socket's open at the same time in my application. One is a standard DatagramSocket, the other a MulticastSocket. Both have their own port. However, when I try to initialise them, I get an error while creating the second socket. The error is as follows:

```
05-23 10:37:57.011: ERROR/UDPInterface(15478): Exception occurred while initializing MulticastSocket: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

However, because I use separate ports for both Sockets, this couldn't happen, right? Or is it because the port specified for the MulticastSocket is already in use? Then the error message wouldn't make any sense as it is talking about an already in use address.... :/

I create the sockets like this:

```
/**
 * Initially set the UnicastSocket to use.
 * <p>Called from the constructor to create a new DatagramSocket to use 
 * for receiving and sending unicast data over UDP.
 * @param address The address to initially use.
 * @param port The port to initially use.
 */
private void initUnicastSocket(Inet4Address address, int port){
    try{
        mUnicastSocket = new DatagramSocket(port, address);
        mUnicastSocket.setSoTimeout(SOCKET_TIME_OUT);
    } catch(SocketException se){
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception occurred while initializing UnicastSocket: " + se.toString());
    }
    if(mUnicastSocket != null){
        Log.d(TAG, "Socket initially set to " +
               mUnicastSocket.getLocalAddress() + ":" + UnicastSocket.getLocalPort());
    }
}

/**
 * Initially set the BroadcastSocket to use.
 * <p>Called from the constructor to create a new MulticastSocket to use 
 * for receiving and sending broadcast data over UDP.
 * @param address
 * @param port
 */
private void initBroadcastSocket(Inet4Address address, int port){
    try {
        mBroadcastSocket = new MulticastSocket(port);
        mBroadcastSocket.joinGroup(address);
        mBroadcastSocket.setSoTimeout(SOCKET_TIME_OUT);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception occurred while initializing MulticastSocket: " + ioe.toString());
    }
    if(mBroadcastSocket != null){
        Log.d(TAG, "MulticastSocket initially set to " + mBroadcastSocket.getLocalAddress() +
                    ":" + mBroadcastSocket.getLocalPort());
    }
}
```

***Edit:***

It also may be worth noting that the normal DatagramSocket will use the device's IP-Address, and the MulticastSocket will use an IP-Address which is configurable by the user.

Comment: What address do you use for multicast?

Comment: As per my edit, this is configurable. However, the error occurred when I tried to create the MulticastSocket. It never even reached the `joinGroup(address)` line.

Comment: Are you sure, that port you pass to `initBroadCastSocket` is free?

Comment: Yeah the port is free, that I know for sure.

Comment: Hmm I found out I forgot to edit the calls to these methods to use the different ports. But after changing this, I now get another error: `05-23 11:24:51.308: ERROR/UDPInterface(15725): Exception occurred while initializing MulticastSocket: java.io.IOException: Not a multicast group: /192.168.10.255` I know multicast groups should start with 230. But I need it to work with any IP-range

Comment: No, they *must* start with 230. That's not an option. If the address doesn't start with 230, then it's not a multicast packet.

Comment: Why do you need it? As I know multicast ip is not a real ip, it's just virtual ip of multicast group and clients can connect to this group. Why do you need ip like 192.168.10.255? You can try ip 255.255.255.255, which stands for _this_ network broadcast [see](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address).

Comment: Sorry, it has to start with 224, not 230. This is the signal for the router to treat this as a multicast package.

Comment: @Nikita: Multicast != broadcast. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address

Comment: See my answer, I solved this another way, which works the way I want it to.

Comment: And as an answer to the question of why I need this, is that I give the user the option to choose: Use a broadcast address to receive or send, or specify some endpoints (IP-Address + port) to send it via Unicast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by using a secondary DatagramSocket instead of a MulticastSocket. By setting the `DatagramSocket.setBroadcast(true);`, I am able to send/receive broadcast messages.

Revised initialization logic:

```
/**
 * Initially set the BroadcastSocket to use.
 * <p>Called from the constructor to create a new DatagramSocket to use 
 * for receiving and sending broadcast data over UDP.
 * @param address
 * @param port
 */
private void initBroadcastSocket(Inet4Address address, int port){
    try {
        mBroadcastSocket = new DatagramSocket(port, address);
        mBroadcastSocket.setBroadcast(true);
        mBroadcastSocket.setSoTimeout(SOCKET_TIME_OUT);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception occurred while initializing BroadcastSocket: " + ioe.toString());
    }
    if(mBroadcastSocket != null){
        Log.d(TAG, "BroadcastSocket initially set to " + mBroadcastSocket.getLocalAddress() +
                    ":" + mBroadcastSocket.getLocalPort());
    }
}
```

Thank you all though for spending time on this for me though.

Answer (score 1):

Multicast uses UDP packets plus the error message says "while initializing *MulticastSocket*", so the problem is the multicast socket.

I suggest to add the socket parameters to the log message. That will make debugging much more simple.

What you experience can have several reasons:

1. An old copy of your code is still running
2. There is a firewall on the device
3. There is another app which uses this port. Try a different one to check

Comment: The message saying "while initializing MulticastSocket" is my doing, but furthermore, your points are valid. Though I have already found out what was causing this bug, I have already encountered another. See the comments on my main question.